# How to parse a set of given problems with random choices?

Tags: perl

Hi I am working on a small parsing script, preferably in Perl to parse a given set of questions. There are always four questions (for testing purposes right now). They are formatted as follows:

```
Junk
Junk
Junk
(1)

How is the weather in India?
A Good
B Bad
C Terrible
(2)

Are you hungry right this second?
True
False
(3)

Which is a fruit?
A Africa
B China
C India
D Asia
E America
F Apple
G Mexico
(4)

A mystery is?
A Game
B Problem
C I don't know
D Nothing
```

So the pattern is the same, the number (1) comes first, then a blank space followed by the question. Now the answer can choices can vary and I am trying to figure out a way to keep it consistent. I've figured out a way to strip all the questions and place them into a hash. Now I need to store the choices that correspond with them.

My code right now can strip the contents above into an array that has the following:

```
PRINTING ARRAY OF Q'S 
How is the weather in India?
Are you hungry right this second?
Which is a fruit?
A mystery is?
```

Code is :

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (FILE, "$ARGV[0]" );



my @questions = ();

my $flagToCapture = 0 ;
my $foundQuestion = 0 ;

while (<FILE>){

if ($flagToCapture ==2 ) {
    $flagToCapture = 0;
    chomp($_);
    push(@questions, $_);
    #inserted question into the array
    $foundQuestion = 1;
}

if ($flagToCapture == 1){
    $flagToCapture = 2;
}

if ($_ =~ m/^\(/) {
    $flagToCapture =1;
}

}

print "PRINTING ARRAY OF Q'S \n";
foreach(@questions){
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my $quest;
my %QA;
while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /^\((\d+)\)$/) {
        $quest = $1;
        $QA{$quest} = [];
    } elsif ($line =~ /\S+/ && defined $quest) {
        push @{$QA{$quest}}, $line;
    }
}
dump %QA;

__DATA__
Junk
Junk
Junk
(1)

How is the weather in India?
A Good
B Bad
C Terrible
(2)

Are you hungry right this second?
True
False
(3)

Which is a fruit?
A Africa
B China
C India
D Asia 
E America
F Apple
G Mexico
(4)

A mystery is?
A Game
B Problem
C I don't know
D Nothing
```

**Output:**

```
(
  4,
  [
    "A mystery is?",
    "A Game",
    "B Problem",
    "C I don't know",
    "D Nothing",
  ],
  1,
  ["How is the weather in India?", "A Good", "B Bad", "C Terrible"],
  3,
  [
    "Which is a fruit?",
    "A Africa",
    "B China",
    "C India",
    "D Asia ",
    "E America",
    "F Apple",
    "G Mexico",
  ],
  2,
  ["Are you hungry right this second?", "True", "False"],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

*I've figured out a way to strip all the questions and place them into a hash. Now I need to store the choices that correspond with them.*

Great, the answer is, the lines following the questions are the answers, so once you find a question, simply keep append the lines you see, until you reach 1)a new question or 2) blank line

update: if you're not going to do the error checking yourself, `use autodie;`
the simple version, find a question number, everything else is considered content

```
use autodie;
...
my %questions;
my $questionNumber = '';
while (<FILE>){
    if( /^\s* \( (\d+) \) \s* $/x ){
        $questionNumber = $1;
        $questions{ $questionNumber } = '';
    } else {
        $questions{ $questionNumber } .= $_;
    }
}
while( my( $k, $v ) = each %questions ){
    print "($k)$v\n";
    print Dumper( $k => QuestionToHash( $v ) );
}
```

Comment: This may be a dumb question, since it's very late at night... how do I keep adding until I reach the next (#)? I'll add some code up top.